# Email Attestation in SharePoint Online. How does it work?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, governance, tenant

Does anyone know how exactly email attestation works in SharePoint Online? I have found two settings, but there is no documentation describing what these do:

- `EmailAttestationRequired`
- `EmailAttestationReAuthDays`

[image]

Would really appreciate any additional insight!

Comment: Didn’t find anything useful, but the word “email attestation” was once mentioned in this Tech Community post. So my guess is that the commands were once designed to extend the expiration date for groups. 
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365-groups/expiring-groups/m-p/29990